# Pdf of samples from a distribution after tossing samples out at random

Tags: probability, density-function

Suppose I have some probability distribution with density function $p(x)$ and I draw $n$ samples from it. Then, I randomly toss out some fraction of those samples $k$ and look at the remaining samples.

Can I characterize the remaining samples? As $n\rightarrow\infty$, is there a pdf that describes them? My intuition is that probability density would move toward the tails.

Comment: The remaining samples have the same distribution as if you simply drew $n-k$ samples.

Comment: ... as long as the "randomly toss" choice is independent from the values of the samples.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for the pdf of the selected samples to be different than the original *n* samples if the initial *n* samples were taken randomly and the *k* samples that were removed were also selected randomly. It is equivalent to having taken *n-k* samples initially.